# Hibernate Update Query is not working in second time

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to update record by Hibernate HQL Query but result in continue loading page.

There is no any problem with update record at first attempt.

For Mapping I am using annotation configuration, @Transactional is bind in service layer,

Hibernate Configuration in Spring configuration file :

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.datasolr"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:db.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"/>

    <!-- Configures spring view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configures validation message property file -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages"></property>
    </bean>

        <!-- Configures database property -->
        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        </bean>

        <!-- Configures Hibernate Sessionfactory -->
        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>com.spring.datasolr.model</value>
                </list>
            </property>

            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> -->
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <!-- Configures Hibernate Transaction Management -->
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>
```

Dao Class :

```
@Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    @Override
        public void update(User user) {
        System.out.println("User ID :: "+user.getId());
        Query query = getSession().createQuery("UPDATE User SET name=:name, email=:email, message=:message WHERE id=:id");
        query.setParameter("name", user.getName());
        query.setParameter("email", user.getEmail());
        query.setParameter("message", user.getMessage());
        query.setParameter("id", user.getId());
        query.executeUpdate();
        //sessionFactory.openSession().saveOrUpdate(user);
    }
```

Service Layer :

```
@Transactional
@Service(value = "userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDao; // This is for database

    @Autowired
    SolrTemplate solrTemplate;

    @Resource
    private UserRepository userRepository; // This is for solr

    @Override
    public void updateDocument(Object obj) {
        User user =(User) obj;
        userDao.update(user);

        //solr repository, save all user in solr indexing
        userRepository.save(userDao.userList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `openSession` use `getCurrentSession`, however why are you even writing a query? You are using hibernate so why aren't you letting hibernate do the hard stuff, i.e just do `session.saveOrUpdate(user)`.

Comment: I have used it before but not working, so i tried HQL query.

Comment: Show the code where you are using "@Transactional".

Comment: @Override
  public void updateDocument(Object obj) {
  User user =(User) obj;
  userDao.update(user);
  
  //solr repository, save all user in solr indexing
  userRepository.save(userDao.userList());
 }

Comment: @ChiragPanara Is this the code where you are using @Transactional?

Comment: If it isn't working then your configuration is wrong and a query isn't the solution. What isn't working if you use `getCurrentSession` an exception? Note that using `openSession` opens a new session which isn;t under spring or tx management control. Make sure you have `<tx:annotation-driven />` in your configuration else `@Transactional` is useless.

Comment: @M.Deinum I think so, but there are more requirements to be **annotation-driven-transactions**: It must be a spring-annotation managed service class and a specific annotations-proxy-technology.

Comment: The OP stated he has `@Transactional` which is pretty much useless if you don't tell the container you want to use that. Also you don't have to use proxies you can also apply transactions with load or compile time weaving if you like..

Answer (score 1):

Your transactional environment does not work. Use this:

```
@Override
public void update(User user) {
    System.out.println("User ID :: "+user.getId());
    Session s = getSession();
    Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
    Query query = s.createQuery("UPDATE User SET name=:name, email=:email, message=:message WHERE id=:id");
    query.setParameter("name", user.getName());
    query.setParameter("email", user.getEmail());
    query.setParameter("message", user.getMessage());
    query.setParameter("id", user.getId());
    query.executeUpdate();
    t.commit();
}
```

Because: If you call it twice, the first attempt is successfull but the transaction is never closed. So the changes are in the transaction but not yet in the database. If you read from the session it looks first to the changes the current transaction has, so you think they are stored but they are in the transaction only.

Comment: I tried above code but same issue remain... need to remove @Transactional ?

Comment: Why do you think you are using `@Transactional`?

Comment: Peter: Is it right to use s.beginTransaction() with @Transactional annotation? I don't think so.

Comment: @Saiprateek I dont think he uses the `@Transactional` annotation for transactions. See the comment of Denium in the question aswell.

Comment: @Transactional is use in service layer

Answer (score 0):

You can also update into Hibernate farmework by using the primary key.

```
ObjectofClassName classobj  = HibernateUtil.currentsession.get(ClassName.class,primareyKey);
```

After getting the classobj you can use to update in hibernate.

Answer (score -2):

```
ObjectofClassName classobj = HibernateUtil.currentsession.get(ClassName.class,primareyKey);

Transaction tx = HibernateUtil.currentsession().beginTransaction(); 

classobj .setUpdatedValue("value");

HibernateUtil.currentsession().update(classobj);

tx.commet();
```

Comment: I already try to getCurrentSession, but it's stop project execution and generate Exception like illigleStatement.

Comment: Can you explain the exception in detail